# Symfony2 user registration spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a user registration form in Symfony2 but i'm getting the spl_object_hash error when trying to submit my user. I just want to be able to fill in the form and create a new user with encoded password in my database.

So i basically have 2 questions:

1. How do i get rid of the spl_object_hash error
2. I'm still pretty new to symfony2 so maybe there a better way to do this

Here's my code:

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\FOSUserBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Acme\FOSUserBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\FOSUserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     *
     */
    private $roles;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->isActive = true;
       $this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
    }

   /**
     * advanced
     */

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    /**
     * @param $roles
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setRoles($roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->salt,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }
}
```

**Role.php**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\FOSUserBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="roles")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Role implements RoleInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @see RoleInterface
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    // ... getters and setters for each property

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param string $role
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add users
     *
     * @param \Acme\FOSUserBundle\Entity\User $users
     * @return Role
     */
    public function addUser(\Acme\FOSUserBundle\Entity\User $users)
    {
        $this->users[] = $users;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove users
     *
     * @param \Acme\FOSUserBundle\Entity\User $users
     */
    public function removeUser(\Acme\FOSUserBundle\Entity\User $users)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($users);
    }

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
}
```

**RegistrationController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\FOSUserBundle\Controller;

use Acme\FOSUserBundle\Form\Type\UserType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

use Acme\FOSUserBundle\Entity\User;

class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function registerAction()
    {
        $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $request = $this->get('request');

        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new UserType(), $user);

        if ('POST' == $request->getMethod()) {
            $form->bind($request);

            $user->setRoles(array('ROLE_USER'));

            $factory = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory');
            $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
            $password = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(), $user->getSalt()); //where $user->password has been bound in plaintext by the form
            $user->setPassword($password);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em->persist($user);
                //$em->persist($profile);
                $em->flush();

                // creates a token and assigns it, effectively logging the user in with the credentials they just registered
                $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main');
                $this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('Acme_FOSUserBundle_registration_thanks'));
            }
        }

        return $this->render('AcmeFOSUserBundle:Security:register.html.twig', array(
            'form'  =>  $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

**UserType.php**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\FOSUserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('username', null, array('label' => 'Username'));
        $builder->add('email', null, array('label' => 'E-mail'));
        $builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
           'first_name'  => 'password',
           'second_name' => 'confirm',
           'type'        => 'password',
        ));
        $builder->add('Register', 'submit');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\FOSUserBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}

?>
```

**Security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Acme\FOSUserBundle\Entity\User:
             algorithm: sha512
             encode_as_base64: true
             iterations: 10

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]    

    providers:
        main:
            entity:
                class: Acme\FOSUserBundle\Entity\User
                property: username

    firewalls:
       secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path:  login
                check_path:  login_check
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /login

    access_control:
           - { path: ^/secure_area, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

**routing.yml**

```
register:
    pattern: /register
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeFOSUserBundle:Registration:register }
```

**config.yml**

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Acme\FOSUserBundle\Entity\User
```

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure that spl_object_hash is caused by registerAction in registration controller.

```
$user->setRoles(array('ROLE_USER'));
```

Here you send an array with string but in User.php class you defined $roles as object collection of class Role.php. To fix this you need something like this:

```
$user->addRole(new Role);
```

Remeber to create a addRole method in your User class.